# Как лучше поступить при сохранении записи?

Tags: php, kohana

Доброе время суток, уважаемые форумчане.  
Для получения данных в форму редактирвания я использую:

```
$one_department_o1 = ORM::factory('department')  
                            ->where('id', '=', $id)  
                            ->or_where('id', '=', DB::expr('('.$main_dep.')'))  
                            ->find_all();
```

Результат действия (две записи, из одной таблицы):

```
Database_MySQL_Result Object ( [_internal_row:protected] => 0 [_query:protected] => SELECT `department`.`id` AS `id`, `department`.`abbreviation` AS `abbreviation`, `department`.`name` AS `name`, `department`.`main_dep_id` AS `main_dep_id`, `department`.`status` AS `status`, `department`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `department`.`hierarchical_dep` AS `hierarchical_dep` FROM `departments` AS `department` WHERE `id` = 23 OR `id` = (SELECT `main_dep_id` FROM `departments` WHERE `id` = 23) [_result:protected] => Resource id #113 [_total_rows:protected] => 2 [_current_row:protected] => 0 [_as_object:protected] => Model_department [_object_params:protected] => )
```

Получение необходимой информации и вставка одной из записей в окно редактирования.

Но если я хочу сохранить изменения в окне (для одной отображаемой записи), то я должен для установки значений использовать метод «**values**» (в «**ORM**»). 
Например:

```
$data = Arr::extract($_POST, array('abbreviation', 'name', 'user_id', 'main_dep', 'status',)); 
$one_department_o1->values($data)).
```

Но так как в `" …\Database\Result.php"` этого метода и кода не было, то компилятор выкидывает ошибку:

> Call to undefined method Database_MySQL_Result::values()

Вопрос: если пользователь захочет отредактировать запись, как **вариант**, при нажатии кнопки «Сохранить», мне нужно будет создать **другую** модель?

```
…
if ($this->request->post())    
        {
    $one_department_o2 = ORM::factory('department', $id);
            $data = Arr::extract($_POST, array('abbreviation', 'name', 'user_id', 'main_dep', 'status',));
            $one_department_o2->values($data);
…
```

**Обновление**

Для редактирования записи в конкретной модели используется такой код:

> > $one_department_o1[1]->values($data)
> >
> > $one_department_o1[1]->save();

где [1] - это порядковый номер конкретной модели в наборе моделей "$one_department_o1"

**Но вопрос в том**, что я знаю только "id" (строки) в этой модели, а не ее **порядковый** номер в наборе моделей.

**Обновление 2**

Да, согласен первый вариант с

> > ORM::factory('department', $id)->values($data)->save();

Я уже использовал и он рабочий, но обращаться еще раз к БД (когда у тебя все уже есть), это слишком затратно и не уважительно к БД.
По сути, это многомерный массив, если б можно было бы выдернуть название первого ключа у конкретного id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще:

как мне подсказали еще на одном форуме,
 когда я делаю запрос в БД с помощью ORM, мне нужно просто, добавить "id" в "as_array('id')".

> > $one_department_o1 = ORM::factory('department')
> >  ->...
> >  ->find_all()->as_array('id')

и у моделей (в массиве) появляются идентификаторы строк вместо порядковых номеров.

И таким образом, я знаю, какую модель редактировать:

> > $one_department_o1[$id]->values($data);
> >  $one_department_o1[$id]->save();

Всем **спасибо**

**Обновление**

Но я же написал:

```
$one_department_o1[$id]->values($data); 
$one_department_o1[$id]->save();
```

используя [$id] строки/модели редактирования, которое я получил:

```
public function action_edit() 
{
    $id = (int) $this->request->param('id');
    ...
```

И это уже работает

Comment: Если ``$one_department_o1`` - массив, то каким образом вы планируете вызывать у него методы ``values()`` и ``save()``?

Comment: Ага, массив, состоящий (в данном случае) из двух объектов (каждая это объект, как-то так)

Comment: Здорово, я думал оно возвращает массивы.

Answer (score 1):

`ORM::find_all()` возвращает экземпляр класса `Database_Result`, т.е., грубо говоря, набор моделей, а метод `ORM::values()`, который вы хотите вызвать, есть у конкретной одной модели (наследницы `ORM`).

Если условию:

```
->where('id', '=', $id)  
->or_where('id', '=', DB::expr('('.$main_dep.')'))
```

должна удовлетворять одна модель, то вызывайте `find()`, если же нет и вам надо вносить изменения в несколько моделей, то можете перебрать их в цикле.

**Обновление**

Тогда единственный вариант - определить критерии этой "конкретности", по ним выбрать одну модель и редактировать её, например, добавьте в форму `id` записи(-ей), которую будете сохранять.

Я не уверен, что понял вас правильно.
Как работать с одной моделью по `id`:

```
ORM::factory('department', $id)->values($data)->save();
```

Как выдернуть конкретную модель из набора, не знаю.

**Обновление 2**

Я вижу три варианта:

1. Запросить конкретную модель по `id` (на два коммента выше) *- как по мне, это самый логичный и читабельный вариант*.
2. Пройтись циклом по набору сравнивая `id`, либо тернарный оператор, если в наборе всего две модели *- некрасиво как-то*.
3. Поискать третий способ *- не факт, что такой способ существует и лучше предыдущих*.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что "$one_department_o1", возврвщает 2 записи, а редактировать мне нужно только одну конкретную. Но у меня не получается обратиться к конкретной записи (я думаю, что цикл не потребуется).

Comment: Не удаляйте комментарии, т.к. ветка становится странной. 

По вопросу же честно признаюсь, я вас не понял.